# postgres (w/ timescaledb) order by returns no rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I am having a behavior that I do not understand.  When I add a ORDER BY clause to my query it no longer returns any rows

Note: event is a [timescaledb hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/hypertables)

```
SELECT "event"."id" AS "event_id",
"event"."value" AS "event_value",
 "event"."timestamp" AS "event_timestamp"
 FROM "event" "event"
WHERE event."customerId" = '8e3a1557-6f00-484d-828e-b57794bf54a7'
AND event."signalId" = 'c6c372f7-b6bd-4b19-9217-676accf723d3'
```

returns one row

BUT if I add an order by

```
SELECT "event"."id" AS "event_id",
"event"."value" AS "event_value",
 "event"."timestamp" AS "event_timestamp"
 FROM "event" "event"
WHERE event."customerId" = '8e3a1557-6f00-484d-828e-b57794bf54a7'
AND event."signalId" = 'c6c372f7-b6bd-4b19-9217-676accf723d3'
ORDER BY "event"."timestamp" DESC
```

it returns no rows!

What am I doing wrong?!

===========
Screenshots

[image]

[image: Image of 0 result queries]

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this, in a query tool, one query on top of the other, both having been run?

Comment: Did someone delete that row before you run the second query?

Comment: Why do you have additional comma after event_timestamp?

Comment: If you remove the ORDER BY, does the row show up again?

Comment: nothing else is running. after adding the order by back it shows up again.  Screen shots added

Comment: Weird. Is it a base table or a view?

Comment: Well thats a great question its a timescale hypertable. I'll that to the question!

Comment: Can you post the different execution plans? My guess would be that the order by uses an additional index.

Comment: The [explain output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-explain.html) for both queries would be helpful. Maybe an index is corrupt: you can try to [rebuild it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-reindex.html)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with v1.6.1.
Query works without ORDER BY, but if I add a simple ORDER BY on one of the selected columns, it returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issues with timescaledb vs 1.4.0 (and maybe earlier)  Upgrading to 1.4.1 and above fixed the issue